# What s wrong with applicationContext.xml file

Tags: java, xml, web-applications

I'm trying to connect dtatbase to my web application. Database in MSSQL server. Here is my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="txManagerDH" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
          <property name="sessionFactory" ref="dhSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerDH"/>      

<bean id="dhDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://TARAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS:1433:databaseName=DH:"
    p:username="GlassfishDH"
    p:password="glassfish" />

    <bean id="dhSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dhDataSource">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="UserDao" class="model.UserDao" p:sessionFactory-ref="dhSessionFactory"/>

    <bean id="UserService" class="service.UserService"
        p:userDao-ref="UserDao"/>

</beans>
```

When I'm trying run it I have an error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'txManagerDH' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before
>   instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice. Please see
>   server.log for more details.

I don't what is wrong in my code. Please help me.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice. Please see server.log for more details.` ==> take a look at server logs

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `aop-alliance` library from your class path. You can get the binary or the maven dependency [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0).

Alternatively, get the full `spring-aop` library.

Comment: I downloaded aopalliance.jar file and add it to my project, so I have same error

Comment: @user3079114 I doubt you have the _same_ error. Please check again.

Comment: Yes, I have the same error. I tried restarted my project and it the same problem.

Comment: @user3079114 Then I'll ask you to give us all the jars you have in your `WEB-INF/libs` folder.

Comment: sqljdbc.jar and 
aopalliance.jar

Comment: @user Seems like you're missing all the Spring libraries.

Comment: I downloaded this spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE jar file and add to my project. I have the same problem.

Comment: Can what is difference between spring-aop & aop-alliance.jar?

Answer (score 0):

If your facing the same problem, then you miss aopalliance.jar. Here in this location you can the load the jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0. Also it is recommend that you use Maven to handle all these dependencies instead of doing it yourself. I faced the same issue here it is solved. Here my post : [Not able to load the applicationContext.xml in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383394/not-able-to-load-the-applicationcontext-xml-in-spring). If this problem is solved there would be another in compatability of spring 4.0.0 with hibernate 4.30.

In dipatcher-servlet,instead of

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
```

Use

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```